# Preserve control's visibility on condition

Tags: c#, winforms, events, textbox, listbox

This is probably an easy one for some of you.

I have a TextBox and a ListBox. ListBox provides options for the TextBox and copies selected item's text to TextBox on DoubleClick event. ListBox becomes visible only when TextBox fires Enter event. I do not want to discuss my reasons for selecting this control combination.

I want ListBox to disappear when any other control within the Form gets focus. So I capture Leave event of TextBox and call `ListBox.Visible = fale` The problem is that TextBox will also loose focus when I click on ListBox to select provided option thus preventing me from selecting that option.
What event combination should I use to preserve ListBox to select option but hide it whenever other controls get focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Leave` method, you can check to see if the `ListBox` is the focused control or not before changing its `Visibility`:

```
private void myTextBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!myListBox.Focused)
    {
        myListBox.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This example will provide you with the desired outcome:

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBox1.LostFocus += new EventHandler(textBox1_LostFocus);
            textBox1.GotFocus += new EventHandler(textBox1_GotFocus);

        }

        void textBox1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Visible = true;
        }

        void textBox1_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!listBox1.Focused)
               listBox1.Visible = false;
        }

        private void listBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }

        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //if your textbox as focus when the form shows
            //this is the place to switch focus to another control

            listBox1.Visible = false;
        }
```